# Task AzureStaticWebApp@0 'could not detect this directory' but its presented

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-static-web-app

I am working on building a pipeline using AzureDevOps, and I face a strange problem.

This is my pipeline:

```yaml
- stage: 'Test'
  displayName: 'Deploy to the test environment'
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
    - job: 'Deploy'
      steps:
      - download: current
        artifact: lorehub-front
      - bash: cd $(Pipeline.Workspace); echo $(ls)
      - bash: cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/lorehub-front; echo $(ls)
      - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
        displayName: 'Publish to Azure Static WebApp'
        inputs:
          app_location: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/lorehub-front
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: xxxx
```

The first bash shows that the folder 'lorehub-front' is presented

The second bash shows that the inside folder is correct files (index.html and etc)

> Script contents:
> cd /home/vsts/work/1/lorehub-front; echo $(ls)
>
> android-chrome-192x192.png android-chrome-512x512.png
> apple-touch-icon.png css env-config.js favicon-16x16.png
> favicon-32x32.png favicon.ico fonts index.html js site.webmanifest

But I am receiving this error:

> App Directory Location: '/home/vsts/work/1/lorehub-front' is invalid. Could not
> detect this directory. Please verify your deployment configuration
> file reflects your repository structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> App Directory Location: '/home/vsts/work/1/lorehub-front' is invalid.

The method to resolve this issue is that you need to change the path to `/lorehub-front`.

```
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    displayName: 'Publish to Azure Static WebApp'
    inputs:
      app_location: /lorehub-front
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: xxxx
```

For more detailed info, you could refer to this doc: [Tutorial: Publish Azure Static Web Apps with Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/publish-devops#create-the-pipeline-task-in-azure-devops)

> Enter / if your application source code is at the root of the repository, or /app if your application code is in a directory called app.

Comment: Thank heavens for this tip.  I couldn't get it working for hours.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone else comes across this post from Google or whatever, I had the exact same problem as Andrei above but for the life of me I couldn't get the accepted solution here to work.

No matter what I put in `app_location:`, the task just flat out refused to see any files.

Upon further investigation, I found [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/722) which claims the following (Emphasis mine):

> The AzureStaticWebApp task’s app location **is relative to the current directory**

Looking at the documentation, we can see that this task uses the default directory of `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, which is **different** to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` for whatever reason.

So, if you find yourself stuck in the same position and cannot get this task to recognise your artifacts, the solution is to add `cwd: $(Pipeline.Workspace)` to your task, e.g.

```
strategy:
runOnce:
  deploy:
    steps:
      - download: current
        artifact: WebApp
      - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
        inputs:
          app_location: /
          skip_app_build: true
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
          cwd: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/WebApp
```